# Customize UISearchBar Results Cell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uisearchbar

I'm trying to display a custom `UISearchBar` Results Cell. I created a custom `UITableViewCell` to display the information but I want to customize the `UISearchBar` results.

I have this code in my class:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PodsCell";
    LinhaPod *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[LinhaPod alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (isSearching && [self.searchResults count])
    {
        NSString *texto = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSArray *arrTexto = [texto componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
        cell.titulo.text = arrTexto[6];
        cell.dataPod.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", arrTexto[1], [arrTexto[3] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@"'"]];
        [cell setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

This code is not working. I tested with `"cell.textLabel.text = @"test";"` and worked.

I'm using Search Bar and Search Display Controller.

This is my `UITableViewCell`
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the UILabels to your UITableViewCell ? Your initWithStyle in LinhaPod.m should look like this snippet below. (Assuming your are not using a xib file for this custom cell)

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

        _dataPod = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 44)];
        [self addSubview:_dataPod];

        _titulo = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 0, 160, 44)];
        [self addSubview:_titulo];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Of course, in your LinhaPod.h you would also have

```
@interface LinhaPod : UITableViewCell

@property(nonatomic) UILabel *titulo;
@property(nonatomic) UILabel *dataPod;
```

Comment: Yes...1 image and 2 labels...I'm not using xib file and in LinhaPod.m don't have anything (default code)...I have only variables in LinhaPod.h

Comment: Then you should add them to your view, in the initWithStyle method in a good place to add them. You can change the frame to place the elements where ever you like.

Comment: I would like to add that if you are using a custom nib file for the cell, before you call your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, you will need to register the nib file in the viewDidLoad method, otherwise you won't be able to use your custom cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller willShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    [tableView registerClass:[MCSelectCategoryTableViewCell_iPhone class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"selectCategoryCell"];
}
```

If you want to use a custom cell in the tableView of the searchDisplayController you could register any of the UITableView subclasses of your storyBoard by registering it like this in the searchDisplayController.searchDisplayTableView.